# Jenkins testng error

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I'm trying to run my testNg.xml file using jenkins. but the following error has occured.
[image]

**Jenkins settings**

- I don't use any source code management method, so i kept it Non
- Build Triggers settings has enabled "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built"
- **Build**

  - Root POM = C:\Users*******\AutomationProject\entution_6_26\pom.xml
  - Goals and options   = clean test

**under global tool configuration**

- JDK installation has set to Install automatically
- Maven Configuration set as,

  - Default settings provider = settings file in file system
  - File path = C:\Users***.m2\settings.xml
- Default global settings provider = Use default maven global settings

**TestNg File**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Entution v1.1">

    <test name="Purchase Order Form">
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_PurchaseOrder" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Inbound Shipment Form">
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_InboundShipment" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Purchase Invoice">
        <classes>
            <class name="Procurement._01_PurchaseOrder.TestCases.TestCase_13_Procurement_PurchaseInvoice" />
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**POM file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test11</groupId>
  <artifactId>test11</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.68</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>TestNgSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-core -->

</project>
```

**File hierarchy**
[image]

Comment: Do you really need the jenkins-ci dependency? Are trying to implement a Jenkins Plugin ?

Comment: Could you please explain more ?

Comment: I'm not trying to implement any Plugin. I just wanna run my testNg.xml file using POM.xml.

Comment: Can you please try once again after removing the dependency entry :    
`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>jenkins-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.68</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>` from your pom file

Comment: I'm asking, cause you have a dependency to jenkins-core in your project...but the suggestion to remote this first is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the dependencies in the POM.xml file, that belong to the Jenkins.The problem solved...